# Can flashdevelop projects output more than one file?

Tags: flashdevelop

If I'm using FlashDevelop for multiple swfs that get loaded, can I work with all of them in one project, or do each of the "modules" need their own project?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: If you're ***just* loading** the swf files then there's **no need** to create projects for them as you don't need to compile them.

---

Unfortunately FD only supports 1 open project.

However it is possible to create **several project files** (*.as3proj) in the ***same* directory**. By **right-clicking** an unopend project file you can select **"Build Project File"**.

If you **right click** on the **main project file** (root node) you can even select **"Build All Projects"** to compile all of them (I think the build order is alphabethically).

I hope this helps.